# How to blur whole screen using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, blur

When I opened a form, I want the whole background screen to be blurred. I have searched the web but found nothing on this. Any suggestions?

I am working on C# Winforms.

Comment: What is 'the whole background screen'?

Comment: The real problem is that the user is always one ALT-TAB away from exiting your app, you know?

Comment: Desktop, taskbar, any previous forms opened etc.

Comment: And the other problem is your window would need to be full-screen in order to blur it, you aren't allowed outside the bounds of your main window.

Comment: Blur?? Do you mean fade out or splash screen? Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84211/fade-splash-screen-in-and-out

Comment: if you mean "disabling" the desktop, so that the user cannot interact with it, then i think this is not possible. you would really make your os an easy target for malware with that...

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth so you are saying I should maximize the window and then use opacity property?

Comment: @LeonidasFett so I should drop this idea and try something else.

Comment: well if you just want to blur the screen you should be able to do it. but if you want to keep the user from being able to interact with the desktop then this is not possible

Comment: @LeonidasFett I don't want the user to interact with the desktop. I simply want to blur it.